# class has no member "operator<<"

Tags: c++, insertion, ostream

I have read through [Should operator<< be implemented as a friend or as a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236801/should-operator-be-implemented-as-a-friend-or-as-a-member-function) and [Overloading Insertion Operator in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712394/overloading-insertion-operator-in-c), looks like the similar problem, but didn't fix my own problem.

My header file:

```
using namespace std;

class Animal {
private: 
    friend ostream & operator<< (ostream & o, Dog & d);
    int number;
public:
    Animal(int i);
    int getnumber();

};

ostream & operator<< (ostream & o, Dog & d);
```

My cpp:

```
using namespace std;

int Animal::getnumber(){
    return number;
}

ostream & Animal::operator<< (ostream & o, Dog & d){
    //...
}

Animal::Animal(int i) : number(i){}
```

Implementation is simple, but I am getting the error: in cpp - **Error: class "Animal" class has no member "operator<<".** I don't really get it because I already declared insertion operator as a friend in Animal, why am I still getting this error? (put the ostream in public doesn't help)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a member of the `Animal` class, nor should it be.  So don't define it as one.  Define it as a free function by removing the `Animal::` prefix.

```
ostream & operator<< (ostream & o, Dog & d){
    //...
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to make `operator<<` a friend function, have it delegate to a (possibly virtual) member function: `ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, Dog& d) { d.print_to_stream(o); }`